# CSS works on codepen but not in local file in browser

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, codepen

I'm trying to implement a donate button seen here: https://codepen.io/jvalle/pen/ImCtq

The CSS looks simple enough, and no JavaScript is required. I looked at the source and made sure to reference the exact same version of font awesome.

When I run the following code locally, (in all major browsers latest versisons) I get a button without the mouseover animation and without the heart icon.

I've attached everything as a snippet, but for extra clarity the code I am using locally (with css in donate.css) is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="donate.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/3.0.2/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<title></title>

</head>

<body>
<a href="#" class="donate">DONATE</a>

</body>

</html>
```

```css
body {
  font: 20px "Helvetica";
}

a {  
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.donate {
  background: #00684d;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, transparent 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 100%),
              -webkit-linear-gradient(left, lighten(#00684d, 15%) 0%, #00684d 50%, lighten(#00684d, 15%) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 100%),
              linear-gradient(to right, lighten(#00684d, 15%) 0%, #00684d 50%, lighten(#00684d, 15%) 100%);
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 15px 65px 15px 15px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #666;
  -webkit-transition: all 800ms;
  transition: all 800ms;
  
  &:after {
    border-left: 1px solid darken(#00684d, 5%);
    color: darken(#00684d, 10%);
    content: "\f004";
    font: 20px "FontAwesome";
    padding: 10px 0;
    padding-left: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 16px;
    top: 7px;    
    -webkit-transition: all 600ms 200ms;
    transition: all 600ms 200ms;
  }
  
  &:hover {
    background-position: -100% 0;
    
    &:after {
      border-left: 1px solid lighten(#00684d, 5%);
      color: #fff;
      text-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/3.0.2/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<title></title>

</head>

<body>
<a href="#" class="donate">DONATE</a>

</body>

</html>
```

It seems even in the snippet the result seen on codepen is not replicated.

Why is this so? The CSS does not rely on anything and the same version of font-awesome is referenced. As much as I would like to solve this, it is important that I understand what is causing the problem here for my own understanding.

Comment: That codepen uses LESS not CSS and as far as I can tell your project only uses CSS

Comment: You could convert the LESS to CSS and see if that works if you don't want to extend the CSS in your project?

Comment: Thanks Dylan, such a simple answer I had no idea how I overlooked it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compile the LESS code to CSS, example here: http://lesscss.org/less-preview/